# Issue with HtmlUnitDriver's frame switch in Java / Issue with switching to a 'srcdoc' based iframe

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, frame

I have a java program to scrape a web page, using selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1 jar.

I create org.openga.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver to fetch the page which contains 2 iframes inside. JavascriptEnabled is true.

I can access the page and parse ok without issues, but for some reason, switching to those frames, doesn't seem to work.  Here is a snippet of the code.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

//The below line works fine without issues, so I'm assuming switching is succeeding.
//FYI if I give a bogus bad frame name here, it does raise an exception, which indicates that //the driver is recognizing the frame ok 

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"))); //no exceptions raised

//Here, driver.getPageSource() here shows no content, just have an empty as follows
//<html>
// <head/>
// <body/>
//</html>
// So, I can't get any actually existing elements inside the iframe at all here..
// i.e. getElements() etc would return nothing..

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.getPageSource(); //shows the full page ok again..
```

I don't believe it's page loading issue as the full source dump from the driver does show the contents of those embedded iframes source ok. So, I don't think "wait" would help here.
What am I missing here?

Tried to use WebDriverWait to wait for frames to be available etc, no luck.

Comment: I guess, issue is not with switching frames its with `getElements()`. Have you tried wait statements here?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, I have tried but no luck.  When the entire page was fetched via get(), I do see the embedded iframe source content as well via print.  I’m just trying to frame switch to it but it seems to end up loading empty without any errors/exceptions…

Comment: After a further look, seems it's something to do with "srcdoc" attribute.  The iframe I'm trying to parse is defined by "srcdoc" embedded, not by "src".   Does "HtmlUnitDriver" work ok to load up(i.e. switch) this type of iframe?  Or, is there any limitation or known bugs?

Comment: Please share the HTML code or web page url